# Automorphism group of a scheme, 2

Tags: schemes, gr.group-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

I have the following two questions about automorphism groups of schemes.
  First of all, let $S$ be a scheme, and $S^c$ its set of closed points. What
 is the connection between $Aut(S)$ and $Aut(S^c)$ ?
  Secondly, let $S$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme, and $S_k$ the base-extension to
 some field k. What is the precise relation between their automorphism groups ?
  Thanks,

```
THC
```

Comment: What do you mean by an automorphism of $S^c$?

Comment: Laurent, I interpreted the question asking whether two automorphisms that agree on closed points would agree, so accordingly one could define $Aut(S^c)$ as the image of $Aut(S)$ in the set of all self-maps of $S^c$...

Comment: I decided to interpret the question in terms of set-theoretic permutations, just in case Sándor's answer wasn't what THC had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what kind of scheme $S$ is. If $S$ is (reduced) of finite type over a field, then the set of closed points is dense in $S$, so all morphisms are determined by their behaviour on the closed points. On the other hand if $S$ is a local scheme, then it has a single closed point, so you can't say much about automorphisms just from the closed points.

Answer (score 0):

The functor from schemes to sets, given by taking the set of closed points, is neither full nor faithful.  For example, the spectrum of a field with nontrivial automorphisms has a single closed point, but its automorphism group is nontrivial.  On the other hand, the complex projective line has automorphism group $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$, but the set of closed points is an abstract set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, and has an automorphism group of strictly larger cardinality.  What you can say is that the functor induces a homomorphism (that may be neither injective nor surjective).

If you want to consider automorphism groups of base extensions, you might as well assemble them into the automorphism group sheaf $\underline{\operatorname{Aut}} (S)$, which eats a scheme $T$, and returns the automorphism group of $S \times T$ (as a $T$-scheme).  When $S$ is projective, this sheaf is represented by a scheme, whose $k$-points are precisely the automorphisms of $S_k$.  For example, $\mathbb{P}^1$ has automorphism group scheme $PGL_2$.